# How to set xamarin forms project to mono android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am trying out Telerik UI for Xamarin forms for the first time and while going through the documentation, one of the required android support library is `Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable(v28.0)`. I tried downloading the package from nuget and I get an error.

This is the error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 28.0.0.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 28.0.0.1 supports:
>     - monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0)
>     - monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
>     - monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1)
>     - monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)
>     - monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
>     - monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)    UITest  C:\Users\FAITH\source\repos\UITest\UITest\UITest\UITest.csproj  1

I have looked up several solutions online and nothing works. I have also tried to change project target framework version and all I see is `.NET`Standard as the highest.

Comment: are you installing this package in your Android project or your shared Forms project?

Comment: @Jason, I am installing in my shared project

Comment: it should be installed in your Android project

Comment: Ok @jason. I will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable` Nuget in xamarin android project.When we select the Nuget as follows , there is no such problem.

[image]